# Django Payu integration in my app

Tags: python, django

I need help in PSP **payumoney** Django integration.

I took a reference from this [link](http://my-django-python.blogspot.in/2015/04/payu-payment-gateway-integration-with.html?m=1)

Here, I almost integrated package in my app. However I am stuck only in one thing which is *Hash generate*. Here are my functions for hash generation:

```
from hashlib import sha512
from django.conf import settings
KEYS = ('key', 'txnid', 'amount', 'productinfo', 'firstname', 'email',
        'udf1', 'udf2', 'udf3', 'udf4', 'udf5',  'udf6',  'udf7', 'udf8',
        'udf9',  'udf10')

def generate_hash(data):
    keys = ('key', 'txnid', 'amount', 'productinfo', 'firstname', 'email',
            'udf1', 'udf2', 'udf3', 'udf4', 'udf5',  'udf6',  'udf7', 'udf8',
            'udf9',  'udf10')
    hash = sha512('')
    for key in KEYS:
        hash.update("%s%s" % (str(data.get(key, '')), '|'))
    hash.update(settings.PAYU_INFO.get('merchant_salt'))
    return hash.hexdigest().lower()

def verify_hash(data, SALT):
    keys.reverse()
    hash = sha512(settings.PAYU_INFO.get('merchant_salt'))
    hash.update("%s%s" % ('|', str(data.get('status', ''))))
    for key in KEYS:
        hash.update("%s%s" % ('|', str(data.get(key, ''))))
    return (hash.hexdigest().lower() == data.get('hash'))
```

Here I'm getting an error like this:

*Error Reason*

```
Transaction failed due to incorrectly calculated hash parameter.
```

*Corrective Action*

```
Please ensure that the hash used in transaction request is calculated using the correct formula. Please note the correct formula for calculating the value of hash:

sha512(key|txnid|amount|productinfo|firstname|email|udf1|udf2|udf3|udf4|udf5||||||SALT)
```

*Based on above formula and applying for this transaction, hash should be calculated as mentioned below:*

```
hash = sha512(gtKFFx|77430fe3cf66ecb2650b|399|this is product|vikash|vikash.g@vsynergize.com|||||||||||eCwWELxi) = Array
```

*As seen above, correct hash value should have been - **Array**.
But the hash posted in the transaction request from your end was -*

```
d58556d31a83a0aa90ebcd08d27c20c5dcc1f30d31e9ca71d9b206fef34762a36f25167445596e9e98ee713516ea00dd317793647bdc78522bad3be94bf51aa9
```

**Please re-initiate a transaction with correctly calculated hash value**

any help would be appreciated..
thanks

Comment: it seem no one taking interest in this post

Comment: please follow https://pypi.python.org/pypi/payu_biz/1.2.1

Comment: i am facing same issue , have you got any solution for this problem ?

Comment: @RaviBhushan I haven't tried that but you can follow pypi.python.org/pypi/payu_biz/1.2.1, hope this helps you to solve the issue